# format a date of string type to default format YYYYMMDDHHmmss

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, momentjs, regex-greedy

What is the best way to convert `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss±hh:mm`(string data) to `YYYYMMDDHHmmss`(string data) using regex or any other way?

For eg: `2020-02-27T01:23:44-05:30` to `20200227012344`

Can someone help me here?

Comment: This might help you: https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#nested-groups

Comment: var moment = require("moment");
var input = "2020-02-27T01:23:44-05:30";
var converted = moment(input).format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
console.log(converted);

Comment: Yes, that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way for me. Relies on constant size of input string.

```js
const input = "2020-02-27T01:23:44-05:30"
const input2 = "2020-02-27T01:23:44+05:30"

const testOutput ="20200227012344"

const transformTime = time => time
     .split('-')
     .join('')
     .split('+')
     .join('')
     .split(':')
     .join('')
     .split('T')
     .join('')
     .substring(0, 14)

console.log(transformTime(input) === testOutput)
console.log(transformTime(input2) === testOutput)
```

Comment: for the first split, it is not confirmed that it is a - or +. So we cannot directly go like this.

Comment: Just split on that too. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\+(\d{2}):(\d{2})
```